# SQL запрос с заменой ссылок

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Довольно сложный, на мой взгляд, запрос.
Есть 2 таблицы:

```
t1: (id, name)
t2: (id, t1_id)
```

t1_id - как Вы, наверное, догадались - это внешний ключ к id таблицы t1.
Пусть t1 заполнено данными:

```
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
```

И соответственно t2:

```
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
```

Суть необходимого запроса - нужно создать копии строк в t1, чтобы получилось

```
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | a |
| 5 | b |
| 6 | c |
```

А ссылки (внешние ключи) второй таблицы изменить на новые идентификаторы:

```
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
```

**UPDATE**:
Исправил

Comment: Непонятно, откуда берется d, e и f

Comment: t1.ID - identity с автогенерацией?

Comment: да. GUIDник. По поводу d e f  - сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 1):

```sql
DECLARE @IdMap TABLE
(
  srcId int, 
  destId int
)

-- INSERT ... OUTPUT не позволяет вытянуть id из оригинальной таблицы
-- вместо него используем MERGE с заведомо ложным условием

MERGE INTO t1 dest USING t1 src ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (name)
    VALUES (src.Name)
    OUTPUT src.Id, inserted.Id
    INTO @IdMap (srcId, destId);

UPDATE t2
SET t1_id = destId
FROM t2 INNER JOIN @IdMap map ON t2.t1_id = map.srcId
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение для примера:

```
insert into t1 select name from t1
update T2 set t1_id=t1_id+3
```

Comment: никто не гарантирует, что следующее значение identity будет именно 4.

Comment: Правильно. Я написал решение для примера, не домысливая то, что не договорил автор.
А узнать следующее значение identity - не проблема.

Comment: Я тоже не домысливаю. У топикастера там "GUIDник", что бы он под этим не подразумевал. Узнать следующее значение identity не проблема, но оно вполне может поменяться к следующей выполняющейся строчке. даже если строки в таблицу не вставлялись.

Comment: Если автора вопроса эта проблема не интересует, то зачем нам это обсуждать? Тем более, что это обсуждение приведет к тому, что нужно изменить схему. :-)